# Create variable names in loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My aim is to create a lot of functions f_i in a loop. These functions depend on parameters `a[[i]]`, which can be taken from array `A = {a1, a2, ...}`. In order to eliminate the influence of the interator `i`, which leads to the situation when all functions are the same, I aspire to create variable names for each iteration.

The example: suppose I have got the array `W = {1,2,3, ..., 100}` and I should create variables `w1 = 1, w2 = 2, ..., w100 = 100`. I am trying to do this with the help of a for-loop:

```
loc[expr1_, expr2_] := 
  ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[expr1], ToString[expr2]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++, 
{
loc[w, i] = W[[i]];
}]
```

When I need to see which value variable `wk` contains, then `wk` is not defined. But `loc[w, k] = k` is known.
How can I define variables `wi`? Or is there another way to create functions in a loop?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `{}` leads me to believe that you have prior experience with other programming languages.

Mathematica is a very different language and some of what you know and expect will be wrong.  Mathematica only uses `{}` to mean that is a list of elements. It is not used to group blocks of code. `;` is more often used to group blocks of code.

Next, try

```
W={1,2,3};
For[i=i,i<=3,i++,
   ToExpression["w"<>ToString[i]<>"="<>ToString[i]]
];
w2
```

and see that that returns

```
2
```

I understand that there is an intense desire in people who have been trained in other programming languages to use `For` to accomplish things. There are other ways o doing that for most purposes in Mathematica.

For one simple example

```
W={1,2,3};
Map[ToExpression["z"<>ToString[#]<>"="<>ToString[#]]&,W];
z2
```

returns

```
2
```

where I used `z` instead of `w` just to be certain that it wasn't showing me a prior cached value of `w2`

You can even do things like

```
W={1,2,3};
loc[n_,v_]:=ToExpression[ToString[n]<>ToString[v]<>"="<>ToString[v]];
Map[loc[a,#]&,W];
a3
```

which returns

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, you will use indexed variables for this.  E.g.,

```
ClearAll[x, xs]
n = 4
xs = Array[Indexed[x, #] &, 4]
```

Example use with random data:

```
RandomSeed[314]
mA = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, {n, n}]
vb = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, n]
Solve[mA.xs == vb, xs]
```

This is just for illustration; one would ordinarily use `LinearSolve` for the example problem.  E.g., `MapThread[Rule, {xs, LinearSolve[mA, vb]}]`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to use a function variable, e.g. `w[1]`, but here is a method to define `w1` etc.

Note `Clear` can clear assignments using string versions of the symbols.

```
W = {1, 2, 7, 9};
Clear @@ Map["w" <> ToString[#] &, W]
Map[(Evaluate[Symbol["w" <> ToString[#]]] = #) &, W];
w9
```

> 9

```
Symbol /@ Map["w" <> ToString[#] &, W]
```

> {1, 2, 7, 9}

Alternatively, with a function variable . . .

```
Map[(w[#] = #) &, W]
```

> {1, 2, 7, 9}

```
w[9]
```

> 9

Also, using the OP's structure

```
Clear[loc]
Clear[w]
Clear @@ Map["w" <> ToString[#] &, W]

W = {1, 2, 3, 4};

loc[expr1_, expr2_] := StringJoin[ToString[expr1], ToString[expr2]]

For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, Evaluate[Symbol[loc[w, i]]] = W[[i]]]

Symbol /@ Map["w" <> ToString[#] &, W]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Note `Evaluate[Symbol[loc[w, i]]] = W[[i]]]` has the advantage that if the data at `W[[i]]` is a string it does not get transformed as it would by using `ToExpression`.